# How do you integrate cocoslive into a cocos2d game?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have searched online for how to do this but I don't understand.  The only thing that I find is people telling each other to look at the example that came with cocos2d.  What example is that?  Where is it located?  All I can find are class files.  And I do not know how to link UIKit and Cocos2d together which makes it even harder.

Does anyone know where I should start?

Thanks

Um, I have absolutly no idea how to do this.  There are no online tutorials (Weird) so please help.  I've spent so long on this that I am losing interest which is bad.

Tate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the example you are talking about is located in the "tests\cocosLive" Folder.

Comment: Once again, all I get are class files.  What do I do with them?